# linux + when change passwd we get permission denied

Tags: linux, permissions, redhat, password, root

We have installed Redhat Linux 6.5 from scratch the VIA kick start installation and booted into single user mode because I don't have the root password.

But when I perform the following:

```
passwd root
changing password for user root
passwd: permission denied
```

Please advice what are the reasons that I get permission denied and how to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

you are in single user mode so you don't specify users

make sure your root filesystem is mounted in read/write

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

then

```
passwd
```

Comment: I still get permission denied

Comment: does the prompt say root@host ?

Comment: yes I get root@linux_test

Comment: was this server joined to ldap? you may need to look into your /etc/nsswitch.conf in the meantime tell passwd you want to use the local possword file and not reset an ldap password, try:                           passwd -r files root

Comment: no - this server not joined to the ldap

Comment: passwd -r files root

Comment: when I run this I get passwd bad argument -r

Comment: I have redhat release 6.7

Comment: were u able to fix the problem? I was curious

Comment: no still not I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

this feels like an selinux issue with the files related to passwd. If something has changed the passwd files when selinux was not active it can have the wrong labels and selinux will deny access to the file. (You can probably confirm if selinux is on by examining the kickstart file)

Follow the instructions from [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/ap-rescuemode.html) to boot into rescue mode.

After you gain access to the rescue enviroment perform the following instructions to force selinux to relabel the filesystem at next boot

```
# mount -o remount,rw /mnt/sysimage
# chroot /mnt/sysimage
# touch /.autorelabel
# reboot
```

Another approach: If you can boot into single user mode u can check if selinux is running.

```
# getenforce
```

this will can either say enforcing, permissive or disabled. You can then decide to disable it while you repair the damage. If you need to turn it off follow these instructions

```
vi /etc/sysconfig/selinux
```

Look for the line that says `SELINUX=ENFORCING` and replace `ENFORCING` with `DISABLED`. After that save/exit the file and reboot. If selinux was the culprit you should be able to login like normal.