# linux redhat + login prompt keep getting again and again

Tags: linux, redhat, login, kickstart, passwd

we installed new server redhat version - 6.7 from kick start,

after installation complete successfully we get the login prompt

but I am unable to login locally on my redhat linux 6.7 server.

The login prompt keep getting again and again , and I cant get the passwd prompt

I restart the machine and access VIA single user mode ,

But can’t understand what are the files/conf that caused  this issue or maybe something else?

please advise how to resolve this problem

from /var/log/secure

```
 17:35:47 linux_test login: permission denied
```

Comment: What error messages do you get in /var/log/secure?

Comment: in secure log I get near the login word - permission denied

Comment: login: permission denied

Comment: Can you paste the whole line? You want to know what (presumably PAM module) is denying you

Comment: please see the update

Comment: do you have some suggestions?

Comment: you are reposting the smae question without even replying to my answer. http://serverfault.com/questions/769998/linux-when-change-passwd-we-get-permission-denied/770026#770026

Answer (score 0):

Edit the kernel booting options, change `ro init=/sysroot/bin/sh` to `rw init=/sysroot/bin/sh` and boot CentOS. When logged in, follow these commands:

```
chroot /sysroot
passwd root
touch /.autorelabel
reboot
```

You now should be able to loggin as root user.

[Source](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2014/09/reset-forgotten-root-password-centos-7-servers/)

Comment: on which file need to change to rw init=/sysroot/bin/sh  ??

Comment: When on the grub, press 'e', then go to 'kernel' and edit that. Anyways, you should have a look at the link I posted as it's easy to see how to do that